# Docker doesn't connect under proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

My configuration is: Win 10 Pro; Virtual Box 6.0; in Virtual Box, Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.2; and in Linux I have Docker 19.03.5.

From my home connection all works fine and also Docker; I can, i.e., make a "search" without problems. At my work I have a proxy and proxy is well configured  (Internet is available and also the browser works fine); for Docker proxy configuration, I have done exactly what is described in this official page https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/ but Docker doesn't work. If I try a sudo docker search, I see a message:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=mysql&n=25: dial tcp 52.6.213.218:443: i/o timeout
```

How can I fix the problem?

### Edit

This is another response, if I try to run something:

```
user@User-VirtualBox-Mint:/$ sudo docker run hello-world
[sudo] password for user:         
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: I hope yes, I read very carefully the rules and also "software tools common used by programmers" are under permitted discussion. And docker is for sure one of this. Have you a solution for my post? Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Did you set the environment variables for proxy inside the containers?

Comment: Thank you very much 7_R, no, because the problem is not related to a particular image or container or --env variable but simply to a connection. In other cases, almost a search command would be correctly works. So, at this point, my problem is simply see correctly a search list. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have proxy credentials? If yes, did you put them in the docker config file?

Comment: Absolutely yes, already inserted and checked several time. Identical to other proxy config which I wrote in Linux network setting, which perfectly work and allow me to normally navigate.

Comment: Can you *show us* your Docker configuration (e.g. `/etc/docker/daemon.json`) in your question? Otherwise it's hard for us to tell what your environment looks like.

Comment: Sure. In my folder /etc/docker I haven't any daemon.config file; I have only the key.json (but is not related to the problem, I suppose, there are only key). Where can I found the info you need? Tell me and I will send you in a second (Tip: a colleague with a older Docker version has this file, so I think that the presence of this file is related to the version; mine is 19.03.05).

Comment: Problem solved, I reply the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: the solution is in this forum

https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/

I created a new folder /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d and in this folder I created the file http-proxy.config. In this file I wrote the following line. Reload demon, restart docker and all works fine.

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:my_port/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:my_port/"
```